# Layout cut off from the top

Tags: android, android-studio

I got the following code, and for some reason the layout is cut from the top. I haven't specified any margins or padding or anything, so I'm confused why it's doing this

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="login" />

    <Button
        android:text="User information"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="userInfo" />

</LinearLayout>


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.sample_main);
}
```

Style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Leanback"></style>
</resources>
```

Theme.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Example.Leanback" parent="Theme.Leanback">
        <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@android:transition/fade</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@android:transition/fade</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/search_opaque</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: try removing all transition from your style . specially android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition

Comment: Leanback is for TVs. Why are you testing on a phone? 1) Maybe TVs don't have typical status bar. 2) If you followed the [guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts.html#structure), 27dp top margin safely covers status bar height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because you're using the Leanback Theme. Are you developing for TV?